# How can I move a floating text or image with the video?

Tags: premiere

In this video

you can see a logo next to head that moves with it.

How can  I do that in Premiere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *Motion Tracking*. You define a part on the head that will be tracked, and then have another object move relative to this position.

I'm not sure this can be *easily* done with Premiere, as I've never done that, but it's a fairly standard procedure in After Effects. After Effects has a built-in tracking system, but there are also plugins like [Mocha](http://www.imagineersystems.com/products/mochav2) which offer the same features (and possibly a bit more).

There are hundreds of Motion Tracking tutorials online that explain how to do this, but looking for the term "Tracking" should get you started easily. For example, here's a tutorial for Premiere:

Comment: Thanks, and all of that with the 3d of the image is there as well? what if some one is walking and hide the person? i need to use mask?

Comment: @Y.G.J - yes, you would need to roto-mask the person moving over the text.  After Effects also has tools for doing rotoscoping relatively easily (considering that it is rotoscoping) in CS6.  (I'm not sure which version they introduced it.)

Comment: Hi @AJHenderson, thanks! what if i want to have text in the frame but the shot moves and i want the text to be fixed? do i need to make its position for every frame or there is something that do that?

Comment: @Y.G.J - Slhck's answer talks about that.  Motion tracking in AE with Mocha can track the movement within the shot and make a set of transformations that will keep the text layer stationary.  You then just need a rotoscoped mask layer if you want to prevent the text from showing when something moves in front of it.

Comment: @Y.G.J As AJ said. Plus, you will have to do the 3D animation separately – this has nothing to do with the motion tracking itself.